# if() else function doesn't work in a loop

Tags: php

I have this table

```
cityreportcomment :
-----------------
reportID (fK)
cityID (fK)
comment
```

EDIT: if city has no comment, there is no row in the table: a row (for a city) exists only if that city has a comment.

for every report, I print 13 cities (that are in another table). I would like to check if city has a comment, then echo comment, if not, echo 'different'; but my code doesn't work.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 13; ++$i) {
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cityreportcomment WHERE reportID=? AND cityID=?");
    if (!$stmt) {
        die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
    } else if (!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $reportID, $selectcityID_array_unique[$i])) {
        die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
    } else if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        die(printf("Error execute from ereportcomment table: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
    } else {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (isset($row['cityID']) && $row['cityID'] == $selectcityID_array_unique[$i]) {
                $selectcomment2[] = 'same' . $row['cityID'] . (isset($row['comment']) ? $row['comment'] : "");
            } elseif (!isset($row['cityID']) || $row['cityID'] != $selectcityID_array_unique[$i]) {
                $selectcomment2[] = 'different';
            }
        }
    }
    /* end else */
    
    $stmt->close();
    
    echo $i . ' ' . $selectcomment2[$i] . '<br>';
    
} //end for
```

PROBLEM:

if `$i=1` has comment, `$i=2` no comment, `$i=3` has comment, `$i=4` no comment, my echo results is

```
1 comment1

2 comment3

3

4

5

.....

It should be


1 comment1

2 different

3 comment3

4 different

5 different

.....
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? The only suggestion I can give is, put your prepare outside of the loop.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "my code doesn't work." You've explained what you want to have happen, so what is happening instead?

Comment: Perhaps the OP want's to check if the row returns something or not, instead of checking if it exists.

Comment: @DaveChen and Don't Panic Thanks I've updated my question

Comment: I think what you could do is look into inner and outer joins with SQL, and then check the value of the comment column to see if it's null. Or if you want to get fancy, "`select a.X, iif(b.Y == null, b,Y, "different") as comment from table a left join table b on a.id = b.id`"

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (!empty($row['cityID']) && $row['cityID'] == $selectcityID_array_unique[$i]) {
        $selectcomment2[] = 'same' . $row['cityID'] . (!empty($row['comment']) ? $row['comment'] : "");
    } elseif (empty($row['cityID']) || $row['cityID'] != $selectcityID_array_unique[$i]) {
                    $selectcomment2[] = 'different';
    } else {
    continue; # do nothing
    }
}
```

Your if/else doesn't work because you are checking if `$row['cityID']` "is set", in other words, if it exists or not... However, because you are using it on a mysql loop where you are returning those fields, they will always be set (exist). I suspect that what you want to check is, if `$row['cityID']` is empty or not, which in that case you could use `!empty()` instead.

```
https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/
```

Comment: thanks, but still have same problem, I've edited my question with the problem

Comment: Confusing logic. Do you want to ALWAYS echo `has comment` when `$i = 1` OR `$i = 3` (only), and then `no comment` for the rest? 
Printing "has comment" or "no comment" doesn't depend on what's returned by your query?
Can you post some contents from cityreportcomment table?

Answer (score 1):

You have this SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM cityreportcomment WHERE reportID=? AND cityID=?"
```

You are binding `$selectcityID_array_unique[$i]` to the `cityID` placeholder, so every record returned will have a `cityID` equal to `$selectcityID_array_unique[$i]`.

Then you are checking this:

```
if (isset($row['cityID']) && $row['cityID'] == $selectcityID_array_unique[$i]) {
```

Naturally, it will always be true. If no records are returned from the query, you will not see `different`, because the while loop will execute zero times.

You can fix it like this:

```
// remove the if from the while loop, as it really has no effect
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // you don't need the isset checks; if $row is set, then each value in it will be set
    $selectcomment2[] = 'same' . $row['cityID'] . $row['comment']);
}
// if there's nothing in the comments after the loop, then put 'different' in it
if (!$selectcomment2) {
    $selectcomment2[] = 'different';
}
```

Comment: This is also a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the comment is empty, it won't be !isset.

This code should do what you want:

> I would like to check if city has a comment, then echo comment, if not, echo 'different'

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cityreportcomment WHERE reportID=? AND cityID=?");
$key = 0;
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $reportID, $key);

for ($i = 0; $i < 13; ++$i) {
    $key = $selectcityID_array_unique[$i];
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    echo '<br>Results for cityID = ' . $key . '<br><br>';

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        if (empty($row['comment']))
            echo 'different<br>';
        else
            echo $row['comment'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: thanks Dave, only 2 things: 1)if city has no comment, it doesn't show 'different' but it's just empty, 2) how could I use the results outside the while loop? I need to echo them outside the while loop. Thanks!